# Java Non-blocking Read

Tags: java, input, user-input, inputstream, io

I'm trying to read in from two different input streams (stdin and stderr of a child application) and print them in one combine frame.  I've never done this before, and am wondering about best practices.

I can spawn two threads and let them both block on the input stream.  Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to be able to distinguish between data from stdin and stderr? If not, then you could use [`ProcessBuilder.redirectErrorStream`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream%28boolean%29) to redirect stderr to the stdin stream.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine, though if you are trying to combine two streams you may get issues with the output/error getting jumbled together.

Perhaps check out [Apache commons-exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/) which is a decent library for handling process invocation and output/error capture.  Under the hood it is doing exactly as you suggest, forking threads which read InputStream(s).

Answer (score -1):

having two threads is the only solution.

Answer (score -2):

I think your best strategy would be using classes in java.nio package. Check [this example](http://www.javafaq.nu/java-example-code-346.html) out.

Comment: Impossible. He is using the streams of a ProCess. You can't use NIO on those.